# Visual Studio - I can't use Javascript ES6 version?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I want to learn es6 so I'm watching video tutorials.. But es6 codes not work for me. For example;

```
const lesson = "Javascript ES6";

window.onload = function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = 'lesson: ${lesson}'
}
```

gives me;

```
lesson: ${lesson}
```

What I need to do in here ?

Comment: Looks correct output, what did you expect instead?

Comment: I expect that -> lesson: Javascript ES6

Comment: is there any configuration for to use that ?

Comment: Template literals are wrapped with backticks , not single quotes.

Comment: Use Backticks `\`\`` not quotes `''`

Comment: -__- I watching videos in 480p quality.. so.. sorry for this silly question..

Comment: Videos are nice, but nothing wins "printed" media: https://developer.mozilla.org/